# How to run a linux cli tool, using wsl.exe, out off a Tcl/tk script in Windows 10?

Tags: command-line, script, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tcl

For a hardware testing application, I have to run, and interact with, a couple of external cli applications, for example a Linux ping to a certain local IP address, from within a Tcl/Tk script.

In Windows 7 (and XP as well, a couple of years ago), I did this in a Cygwin environment, using Cygwin's Tcl8.5 and Expect 5.45, with good success. I could spawn a bash and then talk with 'ping', 'ls', 'touch' and several other tools using tcl's expect commands. When I close the bash afterwards with 'exit', the shell process finishes and I could repeat that with other commands as often as required.

In Linux (debian stretch), the same tcl/tk scripts run like a charm, including interaction with any external apps.

Now, by company policy, I'm required to make all this running under Windows 10. 
I read about, discussed with colleagues, and installed the windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) with a Ubuntu 18.04 wsl image, on my machine and ActiveState Tcl 8.5 (Windows version) and Expect 5.45 as well, via teapot.

The Tcl scripts themselves run as expected, including a wish GUI, serial comm and even ethernet comm from/to the D.U.T embedded hardware, but still I'm unable to start and talk with external programs, like ping and some other linux cli apps, using the wsl.exe interface.

If I start the wsl.exe manually, by clicking in Windows Explorer or from a (Windows CMD-) command shell, I get the bash prompt in the virtual terminal and can type all required tool commands interactively as to be expected.

But whatever I try to start wsl.exe from within my Tcl scripts, using the (Expect-) 'spawn' command or even simply:

> exec C:\\Windows\\system32\\wsl.exe $lnxcmd $params ,

I get either 'file not found' for wsl.exe or no response at all.

What is the trick how to to execute wsl.exe and run a linux program from within a Tcl script running in the Windows domain, 'progamatically' and to interact (stdin/stdout/stderr handled by Expect) with it?

Even a '% dir C:\Windows\system32\ws*.exe' invoked from within the Tcl interpreter %-shell prompt (tclsh85 or wish85) shows not a single result, although the file WSL.EXE is definitely present within that Windows system folder?

Comment: WSL or WSL2; Only WSL2 uses an Linux kernel.  While unlikely, it could name a difference, so I might as well ask

Answer (score 1):

> But whatever I try to start wsl.exe from within my Tcl scripts, using
>   the (Expect-) 'spawn' command or even simply:
>
> exec C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe $lnxcmd $params ,
>
> I get either 'file not found' for wsl.exe or no response at all.

Maybe your path is wrong, I don't use Tcl/tk but from what I can read here : https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.3/TclCmd/filename.htm#M26
The way you write your path is not the good one.

Moreover, if you want to throw linux command at wsl, I'll suggest using the -e parameter : `wsl -e ping 192.168.1.1`